# Unix tail command using stack

Tags: c, stack

I'm working on a version of the Unix tail command that works by iterating over a file, pushing line by line into a stack. Finally, the number of desired lines will be popped and printed to the screen. I have used `void *` (void pointers) as the `data` field of my stack nodes (the stack is basically a linked list with limitations) and due to that I had to do a bit of work with pointer casting and successive allocations with `malloc()` (one chunk per line). I wonder if there isn't a better (as in simpler, more readable and less memory intensive) way of accomplishing the same goal.

**Main tail.c file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../utils/type_definitions.h"
#include "../stack/stack_list/stack_list.h"
#define LINE_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int number_of_lines;
  if (argc == 2) {
    number_of_lines = atoi(argv[1]);
  } else {
    printf("%s\n", "Error!");
    exit(1);
  }

  FILE *f;
  if (!(f = fopen("file.txt", "r"))) {
    printf("%s\n", "Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
  };

  // pushing lines into stack

  int i = 0;
  char *line, *temp = (char*)malloc(LINE_SIZE);
  Node *stack = stack_new();

  while (fgets(temp, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) {
    line = (char*)malloc(LINE_SIZE);
    strcpy(line, temp);
    stack_push((void*)line, &stack);
  }

  // poping and printing n lines to screen

  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",(char*)stack_top(stack));
    stack_pop(&stack);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Stack header file**

```
#ifndef __STACK_H__
#define __STACK_H__

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "../../utils/type_definitions.h"

Node *stack_new();
void *stack_top(Node *head);
void stack_pop(Node **head);
bool stack_is_empty(Node *head);
void stack_push(void *x, Node **head);

#endif
```

**Implementation of stack functions**

```
Node *stack_new() {
    return NULL;
}

bool stack_is_empty(Node *head) {
    return head == NULL;
}

void *stack_top(Node *head) {
    return head->data;
}

void stack_pop(Node **head)
{
    if (*head == NULL) return;
    Node *temp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(temp);
}

void stack_push(void *x, Node **head)
{
    Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = x;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

**Edit** - *following are the includes missing from the file "implementations of stack functions".*

```
#include "stack_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: You should have included your `utils/type_definitions.h`, too (or at least enough to define `Node`).

Comment: I accidentally left out the include statements when writing the post. I have edited my answer, sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The stack approach is dubious. It uses too much memory (the entire file is eventually collected, while you only care about its tail). Consider a ring buffer instead.
- I don't see the point of `#include <stdbool.h>`
- Casting is unnecessary, as in `(char*)stack_top(stack)` - and even dangerous, as in `(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))`. [Why you shouldn't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3403834).
- Always test that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`.
- A declaration

  ```
  int i = 0;
  ```

  is unnecessary.
- Nitpicking. `#define LINE_SIZE 256` is a very optimistic estimate. Try to manage a file with *really* long lines.

Comment: First, thanks for the suggestions, all proposed changes have already been applied. Now, regarding your first point, as I understand it, using a circular buffer would limit how many lines from bottom to top I could print (e.g. buffer stores a max of 40 lines and user wants to print 50). I wonder how I could approach the problem of deciding on a buffer size.

Comment: @NorthernSage Allocate the buffer of `number_of_lines` pointers.

Answer (score 5):

You [already have a good review](/a/226000/75307) with most of the points I was going to make (thanks vnp!).  A few that aren't mentioned there:

- We need a definition of `NULL` before we use it.  I recommend `#include <stdlib.h>`, for reasons evident in the next point.
- We need a declaration of `malloc()` before we use it.  (This may be the reason you were casting the return value - that's wrong and dangerous).  Both `malloc()` and `free()` are declared by `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- We need to include `<stdio.h>` for `fopen()` and `printf()`.
- There's no checking that `argv[1]` converts to a positive integer.  Since `0` isn't a useful value for input, we can work with `atoi()`'s appalling interface here, and error if `number_of_lines <= 0`.
- Error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And to print a fixed line of text, we can use plain `fputs()` instead of the more heavyweight `fprintf()`:

  ```
    fputs("Error!", stderr);
    return 1;
  ```
- We can use `perror()` to get more informative messages following errors that set `errno`:

  ```
  FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (!f) {
      perror("file.txt");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  };
  ```
- Why are we opening a specific file anyway?  That's very inflexible.  It's more useful (and easier for us) to accept standard input, so we can operate within a pipeline.
- What is `sizeof line` doing in the `fgets()` call?  `line` is a `char*`, but you probably want to read up to `LINE_SIZE` characters per line.  At present, the code behaves very badly when the input has lines longer than 6 characters on my system (and on systems with 4-byte `char*`, lines longer than 2 chars would be a problem).

  > ```
  > while (fgets(temp, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) {
  > ```

  It's also inefficient to read into `temp` only to allocate and copy into `line` - better to allocate first and read directly into `line` with no need for the copy.
- Memory allocated for `temp` has no `free()` - this could be fixed simply by making it a `char[]` instead of dynamically allocated.  None of the lines read into the stack have a corresponding `free()`, and none of the stack nodes read but not printed has a `free()` - all meaning that we leak a vast amount of memory.
- When finally printing the contents, why add extra newlines in between each line of input?  I'm not convinced that you've done any testing at all here.

---

Here's a slightly rewritten version fixing some of the above (but still not addressing the problem of storing far too much of the input):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s LINES\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int number_of_lines = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (number_of_lines <= 0) {
        fputs("LINES must be a positive number\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (!f) {
        perror("file.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    };

    // push lines into stack
    Node *stack = stack_new();
    for (;;) {
        char *line = malloc(LINE_SIZE);
        if (!line) {
            fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (!fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, f)) {
            /* assume end of file */
            free(line);
            break;
        }
        stack_push(line, &stack);
    }

    // pop and print n lines to screen
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++) {
        char *line = stack_top(stack);
        fputs(line, stdout);
        free(line);
        stack_pop(&stack);
    }

    // free the remainder of the stack
    while (stack) {
        free(stack_top(stack));
        stack_pop(&stack);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the extra mile of providing code to illustrate the suggestions, thank you.

Comment: `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (C17::7.19.3). Although stdlib internally includes that, I think it's better to include the header that defines each thing we use.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: `NULL` is provided by `<stddef.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<locale.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>`.  It's not a case of `<stdlib.h>` "normally" including `<stddef.h>` - it's required to provide `NULL` either by such inclusion or by any other means.

Answer (score 1):

### `ARRAY_SIZE()`

Never use `sizeof` directly to get the size of an array. NEVER. It's very unsafe, as you can see in the bug that Toby found.

Alternatives:

- Pass the actual value
- Pass the result of `ARRAY_SIZE(arr)` (defined typically as `#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)  (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))`)

If you can use the second one, which is when you have a global static-duration array or an array local to the function, it's the best method, because if the size of the array is changed (for example if I had `int a[FOO];` and then I decide to use a different size such as `int a[BAR];`), I don't need to change the rest of the code.  And with recent compilers, such as GCC 8, you will receive a warning if you apply that to something that is not an array, so it is safe.  With old compilers, there are still tricks to make this macro safe (you can find them in StackOverflow easily).

```
while (fgets(temp, ARRAY_SIZE(temp), f) != NULL) {
```

It was also misleading that you used sizeof a different array.

If you had written this code (and the definition of ARRAY_SIZE was a safe one for your compiler version), it would have not compiled, and you would have noticed that you don't have an array, so you would have had to write the actual value.